# Formatting a python dictionary received via xmlrpc for nice output

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting

Is there an easy way to format a dictionary in python for nice output?

I am learning how to interact with an API/XMLRPC in python at the moment. After making a request, I get a dictionary back formatted like the following:

```
{'category_id': '9', 'parent_id': '3', 'name': 'Headboard', 'is_active': '1', 'position': '6', 'level': '3', 'children': []}, {'category_id': '10', 'parent_id': '3', 'name': 'Mattress', 'is_active': '1', 'position': '7', 'level': '3', 'children': []},
```

This is a wall of text, easily a few pages. Is there an easy way to display this data nicely, or perhaps just to output the name of each category on one line?

edit:

Here is an attempt to print it via pprint, which ended up omitting a lot of the data:

```
import xmlrpc.client
import pprint
svc = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('https://example.com/api/xmlrpc/')
session = svc.login('apiuser', 'apikey')
temp = svc.call(session, 'catalog_category.tree')
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(temp)
```

Comment: This looks like JSON, not XML..

Comment: The API only has a SOAP and XMLRPC interface. I just followed a tutorial on connecting to the API in python and it says you get a python dictionary back, which is what I got.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible it's not JSON, it's a python dictionary. The OP has already parsed it.

Comment: @roganjosh I see now.  The "formatted like the following" bit confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint):

```
>>> pprint([{'category_id': '9', 'parent_id': '3', 'name': 'Headboard', 'is_active': '1', 'position': '6', 'level': '3', 'children': []}, {'category_id': '10', 'parent_id': '3', 'name': 'Mattress', 'is_active': '1', 'position': '7', 'level': '3', 'children': []}])
[{'category_id': '9',
  'children': [],
  'is_active': '1',
  'level': '3',
  'name': 'Headboard',
  'parent_id': '3',
  'position': '6'},
 {'category_id': '10',
  'children': [],
  'is_active': '1',
  'level': '3',
  'name': 'Mattress',
  'parent_id': '3',
  'position': '7'}]
```

To display just the category names you can do:

```
>>> [x['name'] for x in ...]
```

Alternatively you can use `json.dump(s)` + the JSON viewer of your choice (plenty of online choices available, or just your local browser).

## Edit

Processing in a recursive manner:

```
import copy

t2 = copy.deepcopy(temp)  # Modify for printing.
items = [t2]
while items:
    item = items.pop(-1)
    del item['category_id']
    del item['is_active']
    del item['level']
    del item['position']
    ...  # Whatever other keys you want to delete.
    items += item.get('children', [])
pprint(t2)
```

Comment: I did try pprint based on answers I found when searching for the problem. The issue is that a lot of the data then went missing. I can post what the entire dictionary is and the result of using pprint on a pastebin if you like.

Comment: @JakeRankin Yes, please. Maybe that was a problem with your console? Did you look at `pformat` and dumping  to a file?

Comment: I am not familiar with pformat, very new to python and API stuff, reading about it now. This is the paste of the entire dict I received via xmlrpc: https://pastebin.com/Kvfac4W2 and this is the pastebin showing the result of printing with pprint: https://pastebin.com/ASX3ErF2 and the code I use to print it: https://pastebin.com/AWKCp2kE

Comment: @JakeRankin The data you posted is not a `dict`. Actually it's not valid Python syntax. I wonder what it actually is. How did you come to the conclusion this is a dict? Can you check `print(type(temp))`? Looks like this data is faulty already. Is it possible that you obtained the "raw" data by just doing `print(temp)`? If so, you probably hit the max length of your console and so it chopped off the beginning, hence it is incomplete.

Comment: I'm certain it is a dict. It is what the API documentation says will be returned via XMLRPC, and I did print(type(temp)) before posting which returns "<class 'dict'>"

Comment: @JakeRankin Alright, I suppose the two outputs you post are both "missing" data, due to the max length of your console. Depending on your OS you can (easily) increase this. Otherwise use [`pformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) and dump to file, then you get the full content.

Comment: That makes sense, I am doing this in a screen session via putty. I'm sure there is a limit and this is a lot of data. So, I will look at using pformat. Thank you.

Comment: @a_guess I found another page and used the following code to write to a file before looking at pformat:     for key, value in temp.items(): f.write('%s:%s\n' % (key, value)) which writes to file. I would like to print just names and maybe one other field but I am unsure how to specify them? Should I post this as a new question?

Comment: @JakeRankin Just be clear about what you want to achieve. You can just select the elements from the dict which you want to print, what's the issue there?

Comment: I'm just new to python dictionaries, trying to get familiar with them now. Ideally, I would print the data as a tree, but I don't think it's possible to print it visually in a way that mirrors the data. In which case I just want to print a list of names and maybe the parent id or category.

Comment: @JakeRankin See my updated answer. You can create a copy, delete items from the copied dictionary and then use this for printing. Since I don't have the full data, I can only speculate about its structure. You mentioned tree like, thus I assumed the `'children'` key would point to more dicts.

Comment: I get an error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I did not think it would be so hard to work with data received from an API.

Comment: @JakeRankin Yes, because probably you did `import pprint` instead of `from pprint import pprint` and hence you need to do `pprint.pprint(t2)` on the last line. It's actually not difficult at all, you just need to dump the dict content to a file and then view it separately. Stuffing tens of thousands of lines into a Putty session window is the tricky thing here.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of category names:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'category_id': '9', 'parent_id': '3', 'name': 'Headboard', 'is_active': '1', 'position': '6', 'level': '3', 'children': []}, {'category_id': '10', 'parent_id': '3', 'name': 'Mattress', 'is_active': '1', 'position': '7', 'level': '3', 'children': []}]

category_names = [dict['name'] for dict in list_of_dicts]

print(category_names)
```

OUTPUT:

['Headboard', 'Mattress']

Comment: You can then print this list however you want.

Comment: is list_of_dicts the same as the dict I received back via xmlrpc? I edited my question to show the code I was using to receive the dictionary, which is assigned to the temp in my code. I used your code substituting temp for list_of_dicts but this did not work, saying string indices need to be integers.

Comment: Dictionaries are enclosed using {}, and your data is in the form of {}, {} so multiple dictionaries. I assumed that these were stored in a list e.g [{}, {}] but that very well might **not** be the case. I am not sure what data structure is used to hold your multiple dictionaries, try do this to find out and then perhaps post back here: type(temp)

Comment: type(temp) returns class 'dict'

Comment: Okay, so it looks like you have a dictionary of dictionaries i.e { {}, {}, {} .. {} }. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Actually, this is not a valid data type. You cannon have a data structure like what I have shown above in my previous comment. @a_guest is correct in his/her comment.

Comment: Then what is going on? This is what I receive when requesting the a catalog category tree via the API. The API documentation states a python dict is return which is what python seems to verify.

Comment: If the elements of your 'data type' are indeed in the form of {}, {} like you have shown in your original question, then the enclosing data type cannot be a dictionary. But if you insist that is it a dictionary, then perhaps the data looks like this: { "key_1": {}, "key_2": {} ... "key_n": {} }. I will come up with a solution for this structure that you could test.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is actually a dictionary of dictionaries, such that it is in the form: `{ "key_1": {}, "key_2": {} ... "key_n": {} }`

then the following code will create a list of the names of categories:

```
dict_of_dicts = {"key_a": {'category_id': '9', 'parent_id': '3', 'name': 'Headboard', 'is_active': '1', 'position': '6', 'level': '3', 'children': []}, "key_b": {'category_id': '10', 'parent_id': '3', 'name': 'Mattress', 'is_active': '1', 'position': '7', 'level': '3', 'children': []}}

category_names = [dict["name"] for dict in dict_of_dicts.values()]
print(category_names)
```

OUTPUT:

['Headboard', 'Mattress']

Comment: OP for your case, replace 'dic_of_dicts' with your temp variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help Oamar. I get the error TypeError: string indices must be integers. If this is not a dictionary of dictionaries I'm not sure what else this could be.

Comment: Hope your able to figure it out. 'TypeError: string indices must be integers' arises from trying to access an element in a list by using something other than an integer. For example my_list = [1,2,3,4], then this will reproducte the error: my_list["hi"] ..